# tcp header patterns to behave differently from rfc specification

Tags: tcp, behavior

Is it possible that tcp header patterns to behave differently from rfc specification in normal case(i mean when it is not any intrusion or anomaly)? or it will always follow rfc standard in all cases where there is no attack?

Comment: make an example please

Answer (score 0):

The RFC is there to be followed. A host that does not conform to the RFCs (a) cannot be connected directly to the Internet and (b) won't work correctly.